# When might flink support pattern match involving fields of previous events?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-cep

It would be great to be able to match events based on their field values going beyond the current capability of creating patterns out of events matching separate criteria. For example as explained at https://flink.apache.org/news/2016/04/06/cep-monitoring.html we can do:

```
Pattern<MonitoringEvent, ?> warningPattern = Pattern.<MonitoringEvent>begin("First Event")
    .subtype(TemperatureEvent.class)
    .where(evt -> evt.getTemperature() >= TEMPERATURE_THRESHOLD)
    .next("Second Event")
    .subtype(TemperatureEvent.class)
    .where(evt -> evt.getTemperature() >= TEMPERATURE_THRESHOLD)
    .within(Time.seconds(10));
```

However it would be great to create Pattern out of a capability like: `.where(second_evt->evt.getTemperature() == first_evt->evt.getTemperature()`

Comment: Consider writing to user@flink.apache.org as this is rather a feature request.

Comment: Thanks Dawid.. e-mail didnt work! This is the error I got -------------->  
Hi. This is the qmail-send program at apache.org.
I'm afraid I wasn't able to deliver your message to the following addresses.
This is a permanent error; I've given up. Sorry it didn't work out.

<user@flink.apache.org>:
Must be sent from an @apache.org address or a subscriber address or an address in LDAP.

Comment: In order to be able to send messages to the mailing list, you must subscribe by sending an email to this address: user-subscribe@flink.apache.org

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare values from fields in different events you can do it in `flatSelect` method and just using a very simple pattern without any `where` expressions:

1. Create a pattern:

   ```
   Pattern<MonitoringEvent, ?> warningPattern = Pattern.<MonitoringEvent>begin("First Event")
       .subtype(TemperatureEvent.class)
       .next("Second Event")
       .subtype(TemperatureEvent.class)
       .within(Time.seconds(10));
   ```
2. Apply the pattern to data stream:

   ```
   PatternStream<MonitoringEvent> tempPatternStream = CEP.pattern(
       inputEventStream.keyBy("rackID"),
       warningPattern);
   ```
3. Check the values and generate a new complex event via `flatSelect` method:

   ```
   DataStream<TemperatureWarning> warnings = tempPatternStream.flatSelect(
       (Map<String, MonitoringEvent> pattern, Collector<TemperatureAlert> out) -> {
           TemperatureEvent first = (TemperatureEvent) pattern.get("First Event");
           TemperatureEvent second = (TemperatureEvent) pattern.get("Second Event");

           if (first.getTemperature() <= second.getTemperature()) {
               out.collect(new TemperatureWarning(
                   first.getRackID(), 
                   (first.getTemperature() + second.getTemperature()) / 2));
           }
       });
   ```

Comment: I want to rely on CEP engine to find (and catch so to say) 'a pair' of events that conform to a relation. The approach where we pair up successive events as they arrive - while being very processing intensive - for we have a pattern per every pair of ingress events- will fail to catch a pair of events spread across in time that are related.

Comment: I agree with you, but now only this way is possible. You can add an issue here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK

Comment: Thanks Alex, will do so. I do understand the applicability of the approach you suggested for certain scenarios (ex. where we have data from sources giving sequential updates at a relatively low event rate - and we are interested only in specific patterns).